# PayPal REST API: Requesting oauth token returns 500

Tags: paypal

Two days ago, something broke with our paypal integration. Unfortunately, trying to contact paypal support has proven to be of no help (no reply in 2 days), so I'll try my luck, here.

Requesting the token (curl https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "****:****" -d "grant_type=client_credentials") started ALWAYS returning an empty response and well, a 500 error.

Note that the same works just fine with api.sandbox.paypal.com and sandbox credentials.

I double checked our credentials and they are fine. Note as well, that it doesn't matter what credentials I use, it always returns the same - 500.

Here's the output of curl ... -v; looks like you have an internal server error, as the 500 shows:

```
* About to connect() to api.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
* Trying 173.0.88.98...
* connected
* Connected to api.paypal.com (173.0.88.98) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
* CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DES-CBC3-SHA
* Server certificate:
* subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api.paypal.com
* start date: 201
* expire date: 201
* subjectAltName: api.paypal.com matched
* issuer: C=U
* SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '****'
> POST /v1/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic ****
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: api.paypal.com
> Accept: application/json
> Accept-Language: en_US
> Content-Length: 29
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 29 out of 29 bytes
* additional stuff not fine /usr/src/ports/curl/curl-7.27.0-1/src/curl-7.27.0/lib/transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2013 15:59:53 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that is currently being looked into.  If you have not already opened a ticket with PayPal MTS I would advise opening up a ticket with [Technical Support](https://www.paypal.com/mts), so that your issue can be added to the examples.  You will also then be notified once the issue has been resolved.

**edit:** This is now resolved as of 04:12 AM GMT (31/03/2013).

Comment: Hi Chad, thanks for your answer. However, as pointed out in my question, I'm already waiting for 2 days to get a reply from PayPal's support. In the meantime I opened 3 MTS tickets, in the hope to get *any* reply - even just a simple "we are looking into it". But absolutely nothing so far. For reference: 130329-000127, 130328-000379, 130328-000379. - Anyways, thanks for getting back to me, I think it's ironic that I get a quicker reply from PayPal through StackOverflow, than PayPal's own portal... sorry if I sound frustrated.

Comment: You should be getting a reply here shortly to your MTS ticket, but as mentioned it does look like there may be an issue with this and its currently being looked into.

Comment: Can you define "shortly"? Can you define "may be"? Sorry, it's your example straight out of your documentation that returns a 500 error, I don't see the "may be" in there... Unfortunately, we relied on PayPal, meaning we don't have any income, at the moment - please understand our side, a simple "may be" and "shortly" could just as well mean "no" and "whenever".

Comment: Update: Chad, thank you - I finally got an answer through the MTS that an engineer is looking into it.

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm it's working now. However, the MTS ticket still seems to be open and I didn't get a confirmation through it - is there still work going on?

Comment: Correct, it was resolved over the weekend.  You should be getting a reply from MTS stating it was resolved as well.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but this started happening again, however, in a much less predictable way. I openend a new question about that, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163982/paypal-rest-api-requesting-oauth-token-failing-intermittently-returning-500