# PayPal REST API: Requesting oauth token failing intermittently, returning 500

Tags: paypal

a few months ago, we were experiencing problems with requesting an access token using PayPal's REST API. This was discussed in detail, here: [PayPal REST API: Requesting oauth token returns 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705718/paypal-rest-api-requesting-oauth-token-returns-500)

We are still seeing the exact same problem, however, only once or twice per day, instead of all the time as we did 6 months ago.

Please not that the following command is enough to reproduce the error over the course of a day hours, when running it like every 30 minutes:
curl https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "****:****" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"

This is not even close to the number of requests the PayPal server should be able to handle, if I can not even rely on it working 48 times in 24 hours.

Please note as well, that this is the example straight out of PayPal's docs.
We are experiencing this problem for months already, and kinda lost hope in PayPal taking care of it, so please tell us if there is any kind of *safe* workaround that we can implement on our side, like retrying a few times in a row, etc..

Thanks,
~ Tassilo

PS: for the last time we got a 500 error back, the resolved IP for api.paypal.com was 173.0.84.66

**UPDATE** - added content of comments to question:

- this happened about 30 times over the weekend, alone
- some paypal debug ids of failed requests: **2e69a25b371e5**, **a02239857903c**, **11e3c2de8f785**
- the paypal server started returning 404 requests, also, although rare
- occasionally we even see paypal debug code *after* successfully getting a token and redirection to paypal (note, this is production, not sandbox), in the form of: MayflyNG::MayflyException: IOException: no response from 10.72.108.213:11068 Backtrace: MayflyNG::MayflyException::MayflyException(String const&) MayflyNG::Client::rpc(MayflyNG::RequestMsg&, MayflyNG::ResponseMsg&, bool, CalTransaction&) MayflyNG::Client::internal_get(MayflyNG::RequestMsg&, MayflyNG::ResponseMsg&, Buffer*, MayflyNG::Context*, bool, CalTransaction&) ...
- we added some dummy retry-logic as a second or third requests sometimes goes through successfully after 2 or 3 seconds, however, the success-rate is maybe 2 out of 3 attempts
- at this point we don't really know what to do anymore, please finally fix this as this is going on for months

Comment: Can you add or message me a debug id from one of the failures, I can take a look and see what the root cause is.

Comment: Finn, please see the **UPDATE** section of the question for more details and debug IDs - I cleaned up the comments and put everything in the question itself

Comment: PayPal, can we please get any updates on this?

Comment: we just had like 20 minutes of complete outage - can we finally get an update on this, PayPal? Nobody here answers, not even on MITS, this is so frustrating. Your service is more or less unreliable using the REST API, and it's just very frustrating to not be able to reach anyone and to feel completely ignored.

Comment: For everybody else having this problem - our "solution" now is to simply hammer at the paypal server until it replies. Pretty lame, but with paypal's stellar support we don't feel like having a choice